KiCad - error while building a circuit with Arduino controlling a stepper motors using XT60 connector
I am learning KiCad, and I am getting this error while building a circuit with Arduino, which control stepper motors using XT60 connector, buck converter:



I would assume that gnd also needs a connection to a PWR_FLAG, like so: https://i.sstatic.net/p0Vv5Bfg.png

thanks the error got solved but I am getting two warnings do you know what to do abt them?
v Warning: Pins of type Power output and Bidirectional are connected
Symbol #FLG01 Pin 1 [Power output, Line] Symbol 11 Pin + [VCC, Bidirectional, Line]
Warning: Pins of type Bidirectional and Power output are connected
Symbol 11 Pin - [GND, Bidirectional, Line] Symbol #FLG02 Pin 1 [Power output,Line]

Possibly unpopular opinion: getting the ERC right for such a simple circuit is more distraction than worthwhile compared to simply sitting down, drawing your circuit and double checking with the documentation that you've designed a working circuit.

true though but I needed this for a assignment

The warning comes from the XT60 symbol setting the pins as bidirectional since KiCAD doesn't know if power is coming in from the XT60 or leaving through it. You may either ignore this warning or change the symbol to set the XT60 pins as power output (power is "leaving" from the perspective of the connector).
Like @carl pointed out, the error is from not setting GND as a power node. It looks like you've "fixed" this but tying the ground symbol to a new GND net isn't good schematic practice, since it makes it harder to read (text vs universal symbol). You have probably also gotten the same warning as for the power pin on the XT60, which may be dealt with in the same fashion.
As a caution: if your 7806 is not heatsinked, you will start tripping the thermal protection at about 100mA. Servos do fine on switching converters, use one of those.

Thanks a lot for the information.
Will definitely learn from it.
